# $P \neq NP$ and determinism

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, p-vs-np

Suppose $P \neq NP$. Does it imply that there exists some superpolynomial time bound, such that any $NP$-complete problem, like SAT, can be used to simulate an arbitrary deterministc Turing Machine working in that time bound?

Rephrasing does $P \neq NP$ imply that there exists some class $D$ of languages solvable by a deterministic Turing Machine, such $P \subsetneq\ D \subseteq NP$ and SAT is $D$-hard?

Comment: $D$-hard under what kind of reduction? Since SAT is $NP$-hard, doesn't that automatically make SAT $D$-hard? Any language in $NP$ (and thus any language in $D$) can be reduced to SAT in polytime.

Comment: Your rephrasing sounds like a question that [Ladner's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-intermediate) answers.  Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/25797/6973) shows that the answer to your initial question is yes (even if P = NP).

On the other hand, I suspect there is no known proof that
if 
[unambiguous](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:U#up)[GC](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:G#gc)([polylog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithmic_function), [NC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_(complexity))) ⊈ [coNP/poly](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:C#conppoly) then there is a superpolynomial [time-constructible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_function#Time-constructible_definitions) function $T$ and a superlogarithmic [space-constructible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_function#Space-constructible_definitions) function $S$ such that

[DTIME](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:D#dtime)(T(n)) ∩ [DSPACE](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:D#dspace)(S(n)) ⊆ [NP/poly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advice_(complexity)).

Comment: Dude. Stop formatting like that. How many times have the mods brought that up, now?

Comment: I think once, on the meta thread.

Comment: @RickyDemer I recall multiple instances in comments (may be gone by now). Seriously, just use Unicode math...

Comment: @Raphael: Ah yes, you commented on the meta thread too. (I don't remember any other instance in which _a mod_ brought that up.)

Comment: @RickyDemer Oh, I don't know. Then consider this instance 2+x: please stop formatting like this.

Comment: @RickyDemer what is class "unambiguousGC(polylog, NC)"?